# How to render Marionette 3 CollectionView into a table column?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm currently working on a legacy program with symfony 1.4 and a bunch of outdated technologies. Recently we decided to add Backbone/Marionette to project in order to make things a bit easier.

The problem I'm facing is rendering a **collection view** into a **table column**. The table already exists and is functional with *more than 2k LOC* behind it, which makes it impossible for me to rewrite it ATM.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>...</th>
    <th></th> <!-- This is the column -->
    <th>Total price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

All other columns, except the one specified by comment, are already rendered into the page. I've followed the documentations to [Marionette attachHtml](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.1.0/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-attachhtml) and [attachBuffer](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.1.0/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-attachbuffer) but couldn't implement a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cbzs67ar/

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([
  { id: 1, text: 'one' },
  { id: 2, text: 'two' },
  { id: 3, text: 'three' },
  { id: 4, text: 'four' },
  { id: 5, text: 'five' },
  { id: 6, text: 'six' },
  { id: 7, text: 'seven' }
])

var MyChildView = Mn.View.extend({
  initialize() {
    this.render();
  },
  template: _.template(': <%- text %>')
});
var CollectionView = Mn.CollectionView.extend({
  el: '.tbody-hook',
  childView: MyChildView,
  buildChildView(model, ChildView) {
    var view = new ChildView({
      el: '.td-' + model.id,
      model: model
    }); 
    return view;
  },
  attachHtml: _.noop,
  attachBuffer: _.noop
});

var myRegion = new Marionette.Region({ el: '#some-region' });

myRegion.show(new CollectionView({ collection: collection }));
```

Use a collectionview to manage the pre-rendered child by a column selector.  You'll need to disable the collectionview from attaching the children to it's own container and you'll need to force the children to render themselves after they're instantiated.